# How to get the WebAPI HelpPage package to work with the HotTowel template?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, breeze, hottowel

I am trying out the new [Hot Towel](http://www.johnpapa.net/hottowel/) template from John Papa.  It is *really* slick, but I'm having some difficulties getting it to cooperate with what I'm used to for Web API.

I was able to work around a routing issue, but I still can't get the [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/08/enabling-asp-net-web-api-help-pages-for-asp-net-web-forms-applications.aspx) package to work.

Here's what I have done:

- Install the [Hot Towel VSIX](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/overview/templates/hottowel-template).
- New ASP.NET MVC4 Projct - Hot Towel SPA Template
- Build, Run - Works.
- Right-Click `Controllers` folder, Add Controller named `TestController`.
- Choose "Empty API Controller" template.
- Write the following action in the TestController:

  ```
  public IEnumerable<string> GetTestData()
  {
       return new[] { "A", "B", "C" };
  }
  ```
- Build, Run.
- Try URL `/api/test` Get error 404 `The resource cannot be found.`
- Try URL `/api/test/gettestdata`. Works.

Then I noticed that `BreezeWebApiConfig.cs` has changed the default api route, and the {action} is required, so I added the default api route back in:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Now when I try URL `/api/test`, it works.

Now I'd like to use the help package.

- Add `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage` nuget package.
- Add `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();` to `Global.asax.cs`
- Build, Run.

When I try to the URL `/Help`, I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' or its master was not found
or no view engine supports the searched locations.
The following locations were searched:
    ~/Views/Help/Index.aspx
    ~/Views/Help/Index.ascx
    ~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
    ~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
    ~/Views/Help/Index.cshtml
    ~/Views/Help/Index.vbhtml
    ~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
    ~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
```

What is the correct way to resolve this error without breaking the HotTowel template?

Should either of these be considered bugs?

Comment: Once you get HotTowel installed, I recommend you remove the hottowelconfig and move what was in it to your own code. That will eliminate the need for extra routes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After installing the HotTowel template and and creating the application and then installing the HelpPage, I registered the help page area like below:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

But doing so above caused the routetable routes to be in the following order and was noticing similar problems as you mentioned.

```
a.Breeze Api route
b.HotTowel route
c.Help page route
d.ignored routes
e.RouteConfig routes
```

So, i fixed the above order of routes by doing the following:

1. Comment out the "[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod" calls in the config files under App_Start folder.
2. Register the routes in the following order in Global.asax.cs. This seems to have fixed the issue for me where i see the help page, invoke api routes and also see the home page accordingly.

   ```
   protected void Application_Start()
   {
       //help page
       AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

       //api
       BreezeWebApiConfig.RegisterBreezePreStart();

       //hot towel
       HotTowelRouteConfig.RegisterHotTowelPreStart();

       //register bundles
       HotTowelConfig.PreStart();

       FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks!  I figured it had something to do with the routing order, but I wasn't sure what the correct order would be.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting. If you remove\comment out the whole "HotTowelMvc" route definition (in HotTowelRouteConfig.cs), and then replace the "Home" default controller string in RouteConfig.cs to "HotTowel" everything works perfectly including the Help package.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a route of your own? The breeze routes wont work for any custom ones you add.

Comment: I outlined exactly what I did above.  Are you saying that I can't use a regular ApiController if I'm using Breeze?  I didn't think it was all or nothing.

Comment: Not the controller, but the route. You have to define your routes in the routeconfig to make sure you can hit them.

Comment: Ok, but what about the help package problem then?

Comment: It does not seem to be a problem with webapi actually but with the help package. The webapi controller is responding fine. But the Help Area view are not found?